# How to pass GPU Device ID to NVENC

Tags: encoding, gpu, nvidia

We are using a library loosely similar to the given samples by NVIDIA. However, the examples are designed for a single GPU scenario.

On our servers, we have 8 Kepler K10 GPUs and we want to pass a parameter as the device ID as an input and then pass it to the NVENC API in the library. Is there any way to do that?

Here is the init function:

```
static av_cold int NVENC_init(AVCodecContext *avctx)
{

        NVENCContext *x4 = avctx->priv_data;

        x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt = (nv264InterfaceCtxt *)av_malloc(sizeof(nv264InterfaceCtxt));

        x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->width       = avctx->width;
        x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->height      = avctx->height;
        if (avctx->bit_rate) {
                x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->avgBitRate  = avctx->bit_rate;
        }else
        {
                x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->avgBitRate = 128000;
        }
        x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->peakBitRate = 1.1*(x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->avgBitRate);
        if (avctx->gop_size >= 0)
        {
                x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->gopLength = avctx->gop_size;
        }
        else
        {
                x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->gopLength = 30;
        }

        x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->frameRateNum = x4->frameRateNum ;
        x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->frameRateDen = x4->frameRateDen;
        x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->rc_mode = x4->rc_mode;
        x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->idr_period = x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->gopLength;
        x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->insertSEIMessage = x4->insertSEIMessage;
        x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->cabacenable      = x4->cabacenable;
        x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->profile          = x4->profile;
        x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->gpu_number       = x4->gpu_number;

        x4->opStreamBufAllocSize = (avctx->width) * (avctx->height);
        x4->p_opStream = (unsigned char *)malloc(x4->opStreamBufAllocSize*sizeof(unsigned char));
        if(NULL == x4->p_opStream)
        {
                return -1;
        }

        if(0 != nv264Enc_Init(x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt))
        {
                return -1;
        }

        // copy the extradate to appropriate structure
        if ((avctx->flags & CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER) && (x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->spsSize > 0)) {
                uint8_t *p;

                avctx->extradata = p = av_malloc(x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->spsSize);
         memcpy(p,x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->spsbuffer,x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->spsSize);
                avctx->extradata_size = x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt->spsSize;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you tag this with something besides CUDA.

Comment: @RobertCrovella we need a tag 'nvenc' I think which doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

check the nv264Enc_Init(x4->p_nv264IntefaceCtxt)) function.

your answer is in this function. :)